# Call Partial View From Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with asp.net mvc4 (view engine razor)
I have an area called "Reclamos", in this area I create a controller "raTabController" and create View "raTab" into this folder I add a partial view "_Ubicar.cshtml".
I need call this partial view "_Ubicar.cshtml" from other view folder but I have Error:

> The partial view '/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   /raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml

So I call the partial view

```
<div id="tabs-10">@Html.Partial("/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml")</div>
```

Please help me with that problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably need to reference the full path to your view

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/Reclamos/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml")
```

Comment: Hi Rik I added your suggestion and I have the this error:The partial view '/Areas/Reclamos/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/Reclamos/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml

Comment: Hi Rik I added: @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Reclamos/Views/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml");
"~" and function

Comment: Sorry 2am typo. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

For accuracy, I recommend specifying the path as app-relative instead of absolute. That is, start it with `~/` so that it is mapped relative to the application's root folder, instead of relative to the root of the site. For example:

```
<div id="tabs-10">@Html.Partial("~/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml")</div>
```

Comment: Hi Eilon I added your suggestion and I have the same error: The partial view '~/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/raTab/_Ubicar.cshtml

Comment: This answer does not address the question related to Areas

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do the same using RenderPartial View

```
@Html.RenderPartial("path_to_your_partial_view");
```

Comment: hi Chintana when I added RenderPartial I have this error:Can not convert implicitly type "void" in "object"

Comment: Not relevant to the question